How to fasten 3/8" plywood to cement condo floor?
This is a 2 story condo building built in the 1970s. It has a 'cement' layer that is apparently over a plywood subfloor. I pulled carpeting out that was directly on the cement floor. Nail strips were nailed down around the perimeter. I have a sheet of vinyl flooring that I want to install. The manufacturer calls for a minimum of 3/8" plywood under it. And the existing floor is not terribly flat anyway. But what's the best way to fasten the plywood to the existing floor? I had intended to use a pneumatic nail gun with small nails but something tells me to ask the internet what specifically to use. Any suggestions?

a layer of self leveling concrete could help with leveling

How not flat is it?  3/8 will probably follow the not flatness.

Just for clarity, does "not flat" mean that the bubble in a level isn't exactly centered, or that there are bumps or dips under the level? I'd presume the second, but want to be sure.

Ok, the floor has a significant crack in it with about a 3/16" step. I consulted with a contractor for the building and he wasn't concerned about any structural issues but suggested that I grind it down fairly flat and use 116 sealant in the crack. Then install the plywood and vinyl. The floor has some dips. It's just a laundry room and I'm putting in fairly cheap vinyl so I'm not inclined to put a huge amount of time into this. But 3/8" plywood is not flat. I'll need something to hold it down to the floor.

I had originally planned to pour self leveling cement but after talking with the contractor, I was thinking that I might be able to skip that.

Vinyl and carpet do not really care if the floor is flat.  Vinyl does care if there are gaps/holes under it(in time).  A step in the floor will ruin the vinyl in no time, almost as fast as you lay it down.

Oh yeah, I want the plywood under it to cover the "ledge". But I'm not too concerned about if it waves a little. The big question for me has been... do I try to nail the plywood down or will the gypcrete (think that's what it is) just break out? Or do I use adhesive and drop a bunch of weights on the plywood to get it to set flat?

I would double check if there was really concrete over wood.  Concrete is very heavy and it would not make any sense to build something that structurally could hold the weight of concrete with wood.  It would be easier and cheaper to either build the structure with a wood floor or build it with concrete floors that are poured  into a pan. (like a big cookie sheet.)  It would make sense that your floor is a concrete pan. It would be a fire barrier that is commonly needed for a commercial building, like your comdo.  Double check the construction.

Another thought is to forget the sheet vinyl. Grind down the crack. Add some leveling compound and instal some LVP.  The LVP can be installed over an imperfect floor and not show defects like sheet vinyl will.

@RMDman, I already bought the vinyl. I had very specific instructions on the pattern that was acceptable. The floor is not traditional concrete. It's a lightweight material. A relative of mine used to drive a ready mix truck and said it was made of portland cement and sand with a foaming material mixed in. They would pour it over electrical conduits and plumbing in a lot these kinds of buildings. Gypcrete is made with gypsum and that may have been the foam material I was told about.

OK, good that you know. Never encountered that type of substance poured for a floor.

Although at least one of the gypsum cement manufacturers documentation called for using nails through the cement and into the wood below, I don't know what might be in the cement that I could hit.
Instead, I tried to follow what the 'carpeters' before me did. They used very short nails to fasten the nail strips to the cement around the perimeter of the room. I used a pneumatic brad nailer to put 3/4" 16Ga "finish" nails through the 3/8" plywood and into the cement. I also used some PL Pro construction adhesive. Some spots didn't want to hold very well with a few nails so I used a lot of nails hoping that once the adhesive set, it would be good. I did have to pound down a number of nail heads where the nails didn't quite drop all the way flush.
I rounded over the edges of the plywood on the top and, once installed, I filled the fillets with Durham's water putty to make a smooth transition between sheets. This technique did take quite a bit of work. Seemed excessive for a cheap vinyl floor but, I've had the vinyl down for a few days and haven't noticed any issues.
